# Change Background Color For All Pages WP7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to change the background color for all pages? Or do I just have to change the `LayoutRoot` color on every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a Style that applies the Background Colour, you would still need to apply the style to each page, but afterwards if you need to make more changes you'll just need to alter the Style.

An example style applied to a page can be seen at [Using Styles and Resources to simplify your xaml](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-styles-and-resources-to-simplify-your-xaml) while this doesn't include background it should be easy enough to follow.

Comment: Can you please provide an example or link?

Comment: Edited to include an example link

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base page class and set the background color in that then inherit from the base page in all your other pages.

Edit

Base page code:

```
public class BasePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

Main page xaml. Note the grid binds to the background color of the page.

```
<WindowsPhoneApplication2:BasePage
    x:Class="WindowsPhoneApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:WindowsPhoneApplication2="clr-namespace:WindowsPhoneApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="480"
    d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"
    Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    x:Name="root">

    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=root}">

    </Grid>

</WindowsPhoneApplication2:BasePage>
```

Comment: I have a base page and tried doing this in the constructor and on loaded and it didn't set the background. `Background = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb( 255, 109, 41, 100 ) );`

Comment: This should work - I've used the approach. However - if you have a "whole page" control like a panorama then obviously you'll need to change the color of that too.

Comment: Can you put an example of this setup in? I have a base page where I set the background as explained previously. I'm looking at a `Pivot` page. The backgrounds are set to `Transparent`. I tried removing the backgrounds also. I'll update the question with the basic code I tried.

Comment: I tried setting the background in the XAML page directly and it didn't work. This is with having the Grid (the most outer item) set with a background of `Transparent`. Setting the Grid background to nothing didn't help either. If I set the background of the Grid, it works. Seems like setting the page background doesn't do anything.

Comment: In fact, completely deleting everything on the page, still doesn't allow the background color of the page to show.

Comment: Ok, I see. So you're binding the background of the grid to the background of the page (root). I thought you meant that setting the background on the page was changing the background color. This is very similar to using a custom style and resource like @Nigel mentions. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

The issue is relying in how Mango defines the background color for pages.

The only way around it is to use application wide styles and apply it to the pages.

Here is a good howto: [Windows Phone Mango Custom application Theme Step by Step](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Mango-Custom-application-Theme-Step-by-Step)

Following those suggestion I was even able to change the colors dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

Adding following to the application resources sets color on all pages.

```
<Style TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SomeBrush}"/>
</Style>
```